# Class type Objective C

Tags: objective-c, class, types, nsobject

In the `NSObject` protocol, it defines a method that is similar to this:

```
-(Class) class
```

What type of object is the Class object? Or is it even an object? What can I do with the object? Can I get the base class or adopted protocols?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Class` is itself a class defined by the [Objective-C runtime](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), akin to the `Class` class in Java.  For example, you can use the function [`class_getClassName()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_getName) to get the name of a class:

```
NSObject *o = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLog(@"%s\n", class_getClassName([o class]));  // prints "NSObject"
```

You can do all kinds of introspection/reflection with `Class` objects; see the Objective-C runtime reference for details.

Answer (score 4):

It is now

`NSObject *o = [[NSObject alloc]init];

NSLog(@"%s\n", object_getClassName([o class]));`

`object_getClassName` instead of `class_getClassName`