# How to load the right nibs when selecting a sorted row?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I sort the UITableView as in this answer [How to sort alphabetically a UITableView Sectioned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844534/how-to-sort-alphabetically-a-uitableview-sectioned/6844619#6844619).

The problem is now that UITableView doesn't push out the correct ViewControllers, due i have 2 localizations, English and Italian in my app. For english it works fine, but for italian not.

The code I'm using is this,as suggested in this answer [Pushing View Controllers in UITableViewController Grouped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793847/pushing-view-controllers-in-uitableviewcontroller-grouped):

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) 
{   
     switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease] animated:YES];
        break;

        case 1:
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease] animated:YES];
        break;
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Any ideas for this?

Comment: If you sort your rows/ change it, you should also change the view controllers associated while selecting a row.

Comment: Yep, but the problem is that when i push out controllers for english language, it works. When i switch to italian language, it doesn't work anymore. I forgot to say i have NSLocalizedStrings, for localization.

Comment: You mean what did i create this app for?

Comment: Yes it's confusing when you mean English Language / Italian in your app and stuff like that and iPhone has inbuilt language features. so what is this app for ?

Comment: I mean the localization. I have 2 localization for my app. English and Italian! By the way the app is a list of tips and tricks subdivided in categories. The row's text is localized in english and italian. do you know what i mean?

Comment: by localization do you mean sections ?

Comment: I mean the row's text..If i have in a row "One" for English, in Italian i have "uno". My problem's that I need to load the nibs based on the sort order

Comment: Your problem is basically - " How to load the right nibs when selecting a sorted row". Bringing information about Languages and stuff just confuses the readers. am I right with that ?

Comment: Yes, that, but i realized it late. I'm sorry for that,but i thought that it would depend on Languages.

Comment: Unless you created those languages it would not be a problem with the languages. You had people think you were accessing the language tools of the iPhone and stuff. anyways.. let me write down an answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is totally logical and does not need a change in your code. When you sort the `tableView` array, it is trivial that `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` would get messed up while selecting rows.

This might be because you would have implemented something like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (indexPath.section == 0)
   {
    if (indexPath.row ==0)
         // PushViewController to view 1 //

    if (indexPath.row ==1)
         // PushViewController to view 2 //

   }

if (indexPath.section ==1)
   // Do something like before
```

If this is your case, then yes, when your sort the tableView you will push view controllers in a BAD WAY.

My suggestion is that you can take some properties in each row and check for that while pushing view controllers. For example, if you are... (say) having row 1 to be a certain letter or a number or a word, you can check for that and pushViewController accordingly.

But this will work only if you know all the elements in the `tableView` (never mind sorting).

You can check something like...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 if (selectedCell.textLabel.text = @"1")
   // push view controller to view 1

 if (selectedCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString: self.lifeStyle) 
    // push view controller to lifeStyleViewController

    // here lifeStyle is a NSString property //
```

You can check for anything if you logically set  and assign your properties in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and logically set it such that when you perform a `tableView reloadData` after sorting, the flow of the `didSelect` would still be the same.

Let us know if you still have problems.

Comment: Great answer, but the code you insured should go after the if (indexPath.section == 0) i.e. inside the switch, or the textLabel.text already means that it recognize the Cell in section? Thanks for it by the way!

Comment: and string comparison should be fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that yours sortings, regarding English and Italian, will place the cells in a different order. So you have to sort another array accordingly, with the nibs reference. I guess your first row in english is not the same one as in italian, or am I wrong ?

Comment: You're totally right, in fact if i load the 1st nib for the english, for the italian is the 3rd, in example.